# Output Encoding issue in mule esb

Tags: mule, esb, mule-component

I have used to do create XML using "Transform Message" Node in Mule ESB.

%dw 1.0
%output application/xml

item: {
    name: payload."profile_name",
    id: payload."profile_Id"
    }

This shown a preview of output xml as

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<item>
  <name>
    <profile_name>????</profile_name>
  </name>
  <id>
    <profile_Id>1</profile_Id>
  </id>
</item>
```

This resulted encoding as 'windows-1252' how can i change encoding as 'UTF-8' in my outpout xml ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your Anypoint Studio folder.

Edit AnypointStudio.ini

Add:
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Restart

Comment: Thanks JoostD. Yes I have included the above line in .ini file and restarted. Still facing same issue. Any other clue ?

Comment: Try removing the DataWeave transformer, or create a new project and copy paste your XML in there. I think the old encoding format is still around in that transformer.

Comment: Wow! JoostD. Adding the line in .ini file is worked. I tried checking in the preview of output in the workspace under "Transform Message" node. This is not replicated with encoding "UTF 8". But when i run the program it  changed the encoding to "UTF - 8". thanks a lot... :-)

Comment: Thanks @JoostD, it worked for me too.. Just one question is there a way to set this propety in cloudhub?

Answer (score 2):

Easy, define encoding in the output line:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml encoding="utf-8"
---
name: payload.name?
```

the result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<name>false</name>
```

Comment: Do you have an idea when the output is application/java ?

Answer (score 0):

For dataweave in runtime above 3.8.4 I implemented this solution:

1. set output as variable:

> Output FlowVar - fv_itemName_xml

2. inside of Transform Message:

   ### '%output application/xml writeDeclaration=false

   item: { name: payload."profile_name", id: payload."profile_Id" }

and output will be:

```
<item>
  <name>
    <profile_name>????</profile_name>
  </name>
  <id>
    <profile_Id>1</profile_Id>
  </id>
</item>
```

3. Then define a variable as below:

   Name: fv_outputName_xml

   Value: #[flowVars.fv_itemName_xml]

   Encoding: ISO 10646/Unicode(UTF-8)

   Mime type: application/xml

And you have better control of Encoding and Mime type.

In my case I was need to feed that into Stored Procedure and without this workarround constantly receiving error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): XML parsing: line 1,
> character 39, unable to switch the encoding