# Pass http header value to the web service consumer

Tags: mule

I am trying to pass the http header value as the web service consumer,

[httpHeader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuIUr.png)

I use this property as web service input,

```
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %output application/xml
    %namespace ns0 namespace
    ---
    {
    ns0#GetProject: {
    ns0#projectId: inboundProperties."http.query.params".projectId,
    ns0#upi: inboundProperties.sm_user
    }
    }]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
```

I have also tried setting the sm_user to a variable and trying to access the variable in TransformMessage as below, but the same error,

```
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %output application/xml
    %namespace ns0 namespace
    ---
    {
    ns0#GetProject: {
    ns0#projectId: inboundProperties."http.query.params".projectId,
    ns0#upi: flowVars.setUPI
    }
    }]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
```

Error:

```
    Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (3, 32). ---> Input string was not in a correct format.. Message payload is of type: ElementNSImpl
```

Transform XML using the SM_USER header:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
    <ns0:GetProject xmlns:ns0="namespace">
      <ns0:projectId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns0:upi xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </ns0:GetProject>
```

Flow XML:

```
    <flow name="ProjectEC">
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %output application/xml
    %namespace ns0 namespace
    ---
    {
    ns0#GetProject: {
    ns0#projectId: inboundProperties."http.query.params".projectId ,
    ns0#upi: inboundProperties.SM_USER
    }
    }]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="ECDataService_Consumer" operation="GetProject" doc:name="ECWebServiceConsumer"/>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
    <set-variable variableName="extractJsondata" value="#[json:GetProjectResponse/GetProjectResult]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars.extractJsondata]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
    </flow>
```

Can someone tell me if I am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Something wrong with the structure of the payload, not in xml format. Keep logger immediately after dataweave and check whether it is a valid xml structure.

Comment: XML seems to be fine, updated my question with the XML

Comment: Can you post the xml

Comment: I have updated my question with the Flow XML and also with the Transform XML

Answer (score 0):

Few checks

1. Check whether your xml is the exact format which your webservice is really looking for. or
2. Change the  encoding from `encoding='windows-1252'` to `UTF-8`. Follow the url [Output Encoding issue in mule esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261145/output-encoding-issue-in-mule-esb).     or
3. As trial and error version directly use the xml in postman to hit webservice ( without making dataweave to do the transformation).  or
4. Make sure  you have no space `<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>` before starting of xml greater sysmbol tag.

Check the above 4 steps anyone of this might cause issue. Step 3 will be helpful for testing.

Comment: thanks for sharing the checks. I have given the input value in integer which was expecting to be an integer. It works now. thanks